# pass variables wtih message string in globalization using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have problem while defining keys in resource file for globalization. i want to display message like that
 "Hello 'xyz'. you are successfully logged in your username is 'UserName' and password is '412341' "

for this task now i need to define at least 5 keys is resource file. is these any way that i pass variable that not changes in specific language.

```
@Resources.Hello waheed   @Resources.Msg @Resources.UserName xyz @Resources.Password 1234
```

i want to do this in single message like

```
@Resource.Msg(user,username, password)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define "MessageString" key in resource file with value:

```
"Hello '{0}'. you are successfully logged in your username is '{1}' and password is '{2}' "
```

And use like this:

```
String.Format(@Resources.MessageString, user,username, password);
```